# Netcore 2.1 ServiceCollection adding generic typed HttpClients not resolving as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have come across an issue with Netcore 2.1 adding multiple generic typed *HttpClient* to the *ServiceCollection*. This does not work as expected, and it is giving me strange results.

Consider my test

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddHttpClient<IHttpGenericClientFactory<test1>, HttpGenericClientFactory<test1>>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test1.com/");
});

services.AddHttpClient<IHttpGenericClientFactory<test2>, HttpGenericClientFactory<test2>>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test2.com/");
});
```

Now when trying to resolve each service

```
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var service1 = provider.GetService<IHttpGenericClientFactory<test1>>();
var service2 = provider.GetService<IHttpGenericClientFactory<test2>>();
```

When I check *service1.BaseAddress* the value is "https://test2.com/" and *service2.BaseAddress* is also "https://test2.com/". No matter what I have tried the service is always resolving or referencing the last generic typed service that has been added. Is this a bug in the framework? Anyone know why this doesn't work properly? It's definitely something to do with the generic typed http clients.

My generic class and interface

```
public interface IHttpGenericClientFactory<out T3>
{
    HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }
    Task<T1> Get<T1, T2>(T2 request, string path);
}

public class HttpGenericClientFactory<T3> : IHttpGenericClientFactory<T3>
{
    public HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }

    public HttpGenericClientFactory(HttpClient httpClient) => this.HttpClient = httpClient;

    public async Task<T1> Get<T1,T2>(T2 request, string path)
    {
        var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(path);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T1>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot resolve based on difference in the generic type argument of the generic type argument. The best thing I can recommend is to create concrete derivations that you can then reference explicitly:

```
public class Test1ClientFactory : HttpGenericClientFactory<Test1> {}

public class Test2ClientFactory : HttpGenericClientFactory<Test2> {}
```

Then:

```
services.AddHttpClient<Test1ClientFactory>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test1.com/");
});

services.AddHttpClient<Test2ClientFactory>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test2.com/");
});
```

Comment: Just tried this buddy but same result. I think you may be right though about trying to resolve with generic types for httpclient services.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I didn't make it clear that you'd then also need to inject these derived classes instead.

Comment: I went with an abstract class instead of trying to make it a generic interface and it works fine this way

Comment: @JamesDev can you share how you do that?